# Is there any way to generate random numbers in javascript without using the math.random() function?

Tags: javascript, random

I am trying to generate random numbers between 0 and 9 in JavaScript without using the builtin function `math.random()`. I need to find out a solution for this problem.

Comment: You could search for pseudo-random-number-generator (PRNG) algorithms and implement one yourself. Or download random data from random.org. Otherwise, no, it's pretty much `Math.random`.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `Math.random()`?

Comment: You could seed your own implementation with a high-resolution timestamp on page load.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to create your own pseudorandom algorithm? If you are only trying to avoid `Math.random`, you could also use `crypto.getRandomValues`. You need to convert the output though.

Comment: But, why? Are you trying to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 6):

You could just use the mouse position and the time as random noise:

```
// Expose the current mouse position
let clientX = 0;
window.onmousemove = e => clientX = e.clientX;

// Generate random values and show them:
setInterval(() => {
  document.body.textContent = (+new Date + clientX) % 10;
}, 100);
```

(Note that this is not random enough to be used in cryptographic / security relevant code)

Comment: [try it](http://jsbin.com/jesezitemo/1/edit?output)